# useContext between two components isn't updated value from component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I try to implement useContext as a bridge between two components that works when a user click certain products, it will change the 'Credentials / [product]'. But, it doesn't seems that the default value getting updated.

Here's my code:

All of them are inside the same folder.

**_hooks/context/ProductContext.tsx**

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

type productContextType = {
  product: string;
  setProduct: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
};

const productContextDefaultValues: productContextType = {
  product: '',
  setProduct: (): string => '',
};

const ProductContext = createContext<productContextType>(productContextDefaultValues);

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const useProduct = () => useContext(ProductContext);

export const ProductProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState<string>('mmyeah');
  const value = { product, setProduct };

  return (
    <>
      <ProductContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ProductContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

**_components/sidebar/sidebar.tsx**

```
import { ProductProvider, useProduct } from '/_hooks/context/ProductContext';

const items = {[]}

const SideNav = () => {

  const { product, setProduct } = useProduct();

  useEffect(() => {
    setProduct(pathname);
    console.log(product);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <ProductProvider>
        <Container className="w-auto m-0">
          // the mapping of items
        </Container>
      </ProductProvider>
    </>
  );

}
```

**_components/credentials-container/credentials.tsx**

```
import { ProductProvider, useProduct } from '/_hooks/context/ProductContext';

type ContainerProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const CredentialsContainer = ({ children }: ContainerProps) => {
  const { product } = useProduct();
  console.log(product);

  return (
    <ProductProvider>
      <Container className="m-0 p-0">
        <h3> Credentials / {product} </h3>
      </Container>
    </ProductProvider>
  );
};

export default CredentialsContainer;
```

I try to omit and use the `<ProductProvider>` over and over but i think that doesn't seem the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue you are facing is related to the way you are using the ProductProvider in your components. The problem is that you are wrapping each component with a new instance of ProductProvider, which creates separate instances of the context and does not allow them to share the same state.
To resolve this issue, you should ensure that all components that need access to the ProductContext share the same instance of ProductProvider. You should wrap your top-level component with ProductProvider so that all child components can access the same context and state.

```html
// _hooks/context/ProductContext.tsx

import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

type ProductContextType = {
  product: string;
  setProduct: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
};

const ProductContext = createContext<ProductContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const useProduct = () => {
  const context = useContext(ProductContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useProduct must be used within a ProductProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

export const ProductProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState<string>('mmyeah');

  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider value={{ product, setProduct }}>
      {children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
};

// _components/sidebar/sidebar.tsx

import { useProduct } from '/_hooks/context/ProductContext';

const SideNav = () => {
  const { product, setProduct } = useProduct();

  useEffect(() => {
    setProduct(pathname);
    console.log(product);
  }, [pathname]);

  return (
    <Container className="w-auto m-0">
      {/* Mapping of items */}
    </Container>
  );
};

// _components/credentials-container/credentials.tsx

import { useProduct } from '/_hooks/context/ProductContext';

const CredentialsContainer = () => {
  const { product } = useProduct();

  return (
    <Container className="m-0 p-0">
      <h3> Credentials / {product} </h3>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CredentialsContainer;

// App.js

import { ProductProvider } from '/_hooks/context/ProductContext';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ProductProvider>
      {/* Your main application content here */}
    </ProductProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you! I wrap the provider the children inside the layout.tsx, is it the best practice?

Comment: You can use providers like that if you are sure it's not causing any other side effects and you only need data in certain child components instead of the whole layout. There are no such best practices, if it fits your use case and does not cause side effects, then go for it.